# .zprofile only being recognized once

Tags: android, shell, path, adb, iterm

I use iTerm and zshell on a Mac with OSX 10.10.5

I open a new iTerm session and do "adb devices" 
The command is not recognized 
I delete my .zprofile, recreate it, save it, do "source .zprofile" 
I do "adb devices" again and this time it works 
I quit the iTerm session and start a new one 
I do "adb devices" and the command is no longer recognized. 
This is not specific to the adb devices command. I have tried to do other things that would require the .zprofile and been unable to until I recreate the .zprofile 
I have also seen this behavior with the .bash_profile

Here are the contents of my .zprofile:

```
  ANDROID_HOME=/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk
    export ANDROID_HOME
    export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/Users/username/.android/avd
    PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_AVD_HOME:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools
    export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
    export PATH
```

What is going on? Why am I having to delete and recreate my .zprofile every time I open a new iTerm session?

Comment: What do you mean by "have to recreate"? Is something secretly deleting/editing your .zprofile, when you setup your new iTerm session?

Comment: Nevermind, I fixed it. The problem was that I was putting my exported paths in the .zprofile. I needed to put them into the .zshrc file because I'm not using a login shell.

Comment: Be careful with this solution. If you do it correctly, it's fine. If you write the PATH assignment in a way that the current PATH is *extended*, it will be extended again and again for each subshell which you invoke.